# Resume interrupted copy

Tags: clipboard

I'm backing up an old hard drive and copying about 300GB of files. It had about 50GB left when I got a kernel panic and now I want to resume the copying. Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu? (A don't copy if file already exists but copy all files that don't already exist argument?)

Comment: This will depend on how you were doing the copy....

Answer (score 7):

[rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Examples) usually only copies what's missing or changed, there seem to be also some GUIs for it.

The command for you might look like as follows, copying recursively and preserving permissions, timestamps etc. (*archive*), *verbose* output, use compression (*zip*) during transfer, showing *Progress*:

`rsync -avzP /media/oldhd/ /media/newhd/` in some casese you may need to prepend `sudo` if files are from different users.

Answer (score 1):

What did you start the copy operation with?

Nautilus gives you this option:

[image: Nautilus dialog]

Hit the 'apply this action to all files' and it will skip all that has already been copied.

But it does depend on how you copy the files.

Command line: `cp` with the option `-n` will skip all existing files.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good solution. If any files were only partially copied, then skipping them will leave the half-copied version at the destination.

Comment: On our systems partially copied files are flagged by the system and both nautilus and cp overwrite that file. Now this might be redhat only but I assumed this to be Linux's way...

Comment: I've never heard of any such feature. Can you point to a manual page or other documentation somewhere that describes this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a synchronization software like freefilesync to compare the folders (by file content), and finish the transfer by setting up the appropriate synchronisation configurations.

Look [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/compare-and-synchronize-folders-with.html) on how to install freefilesync.

You can also try "conduit" from the official repositories, but this I have never tried.